# Remove HttpContext.Current.Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, session, httpcontext

I have an application which stores session variables. When I do the logout I call the RemoveAll() method on available sessions.

The method seems not working. Do you know how it is possible to force removing a Session variable?

Regards.

Comment: "The method seems not working." is not a good description of your problem. How do you know? What are the symptoms? What _is_ happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Session.Abandon()
```

cancels the current session

```
Session.Clear()
```

will just clear the session data and the the session will remain alive

more Details:

`Session.Abandon()` method destroys all the objects stored in a Session object and releases their resources. If you do not call the Abandon method explicitly, the server destroys these objects when the session times out(I may add:`Session_OnEnd` event is triggered)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310.aspx

`Session.Clear()` just removes all values (content) from the Object. The session with the same key is still alive.

Comment: Thank you very much. Whar the difference between two methods? Does Abandon() remove the object saved in a specific session? What does Clear() method do exactly? Does it restore the session object to its default?

Comment: @Massimiliano  **Regarding:** Session_OnEnd event is triggered. **NOTE:** For out of proc session store providers(SQL or StateServer), Session_OnEnd is not triggered