# Remove current session from Class Library using HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Remove HttpContext.Current.Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927766/remove-httpcontext-current-session)

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

Does this have the same effect as

```
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
```

`HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear()` and `.Abandon()` is not removing the current session when called from from a Class library.

Comment: Are `Session` and `HttpContext.Current.Session` the same object? If yes, this clearly does the same thing. If not, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same thing the only major difference is that the getter for Page.Session returns the context session. I will quote the MSDN article here

> This property is a static property of the HttpContext class. The property stores the HttpContext instance that applies to the current request. The properties of this instance are the non-static properties of the HttpContext class.
>   You can also use the Page.Context property to access the HttpContext object for the current HTTP request.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: In addition to .clear() and .abandon() had to use FormsAuthentication.SignOut() so that User is logged out of application. It is a asp.net web application with authentication mode="Forms"